# Retrieve resulting SQL from pg_execute()

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

`pg_prepare()` receives a preliminary piece of SQL, which will in turn be populated with parameters using `pg_execute()`.

Is there a way to get that resulting SQL so that I can print and debug it?

Comment: I think PDO allows this, by dumping the statement or the result object. Not sure about the `pg_*` family of functions. Also note that you can configure the server to log queries.

Comment: The query argument passed to `pg_prepare` is transfered to the postgres server exactly as submitted by the PHP code including the `$N` placeholders. No rewriting or post-processing takes place. Can you give examples of what you'd like to print as debug output?

Comment: In example, I pass to pg_prepare() `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pk = $1`, then pg_execute() will give me `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pk = 50`. Then I print that string to see if it was filled properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, as prepared statements are a server-side thing. From the documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-prepare.html :

> A prepared statement is a server-side object that can be used to optimize performance. When the PREPARE statement is executed, the specified statement is parsed, analyzed, and rewritten. When an EXECUTE command is subsequently issued, the prepared statement is planned and executed. This division of labor avoids repetitive parse analysis work, while allowing the execution plan to depend on the specific parameter values supplied.

This means that even the server doesn't "fill in" the data in a raw string, but parses and "compiles" the statement in the process of preparing it, then passes both the compiled statement and the data to the planner.